# Spotfire Automatic Reload Data

Tags: database, spotfire, tibco

Hi I currently table2 in Spotfire that's based on table1(table2 is added from table1). Right now table1 loads data on demand from an information link and I'm looking to see if there are ways to have table2 also reload its data everytime table1 gets new data on demand. Otherwise I end up having to go into Edit - Data Table Properties - Refresh Data, and I would like to avoid having to do this everytime I load new on demand data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the relation of table2 to table1? What are their differences? Is it an exact copy, or are you limiting the data, or...?

Comment: sorry if I'm not clear, table2 is basically an exact copy of table1. I used Add Data Table - From Current Analysis - table1 in spotfire. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so what's the point of table2? If it's an exact copy, why not just use table1?

Comment: table2 would not be the end product, it's a means of appending/inserting rows and columns to data in table1, eventually resulting in a combined table that pulls data from multiple sources. There would be multiple "table2"s along the process as rows/columns get inserted in.

Comment: I'm not following, but it seems like you have an [x, y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) in which you are potentially going about this the wrong way.

Comment: ok i suppose the best way to put this is I'm trying to insert rows and columns from different "load-on-demand" data sources into one table, but the order of inserting rows/columns forces me to go the route of creating duplicate tables. Otherwise if I inserted rows after I inserted columns into the same table, the new rows wouldn't have the matching inserted column values. In the case of having duplicate tables for each time i insert rows or columns ,the order of operation doesnt matter anymore and provides more flexibility to me.

Comment: So you're trying to combine the data from two tables with the same structure?

Comment: Wouldn't the structure be different when I'm adding columns to an existing data table?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like table2 is set to have the data Embedded.  If table2 is changed from Embedded to Linked in the Data Table Property, it should always update when table1 updates.